# php strtotime input format

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

As `strtotime()` converts valid date formats to UNIX timestamp. If my input is in `dd-mm-yyyy` format (e.g. `09-10-2014`) and `mm-dd-yyyy` (e.g. `10-09-2014`), how to make sure that `strtotime` convert it to correct timestamp?

Comment: [Read the Friendly Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)... if you have `mm-dd-yyyy`, change it to `mm/dd/yyyy `

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '05-09-2014');
print_r( $date->getTimestamp() );

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '09-05-2014');
print_r( $date->getTimestamp() );
```

#### [Live Preview](https://eval.in/188889)

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly input format, you could do something like this:

//  for DD-MM-YYYY

```
$date = '09-05-2014'; // 09 May 2014
$converted = implode('-',array_reverse(explode('-', $date))); // returns 2014-05-09
```

//  for MM-DD-YYYY , as Mark Baker mentioned above

```
$date = '05-09-2014'; // 09 May 2014
$converted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $date))); // returns 2014-05-09
```